# Inherit a class as static

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, pthreads

I have the following structure in C++:

```
class A
{
protected:
  int a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  static void initThreads();  //Initialize threads (pthreads)
  /* Threads */
  static void* send(void*);
  static void* receive(void*);
}
```

These functions "send" and "receive" operate on "a". But a non-static member cannot be edited in a static function. Because send and receive are threads, hence they need to be defined as static. I would have only 1 object of class B, though there are multiple objects of class A.

So, is there a way to use "a" within "send" and "receive" in some manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static member functions don't work on non-static members because they don't have an object attached to them; they are missing the implied `this` pointer that gets passed invisibly to non-static member functions.

The way around this is to explicitly pass a pointer to an object to work with. Your static function will have access to the private and protected members of the object, because it's part of the class.

Answer (score 3):

`send` and `receive` are threads, and they need to be static - that's fine. But you can forward the threading to B class itself:

```
class B
{
public:
   static void* send(void* param)
   {
       // param is of B*
       B* pThis = (B*)param;
       pThis->send_impl();

       return (void*)0;
   }           

   void send_impl() { /* Use 'this'*/ }
};
```

Of course, you need to pass a valid B* to `send` function.

Or you have have a structure that would hold A*, and some flag that would mention the object is A or B. In this case, you can allocate given structure on heap (preferably), and pass that structure to `send` thread.

In `send` function, using that flag, you can determine if underlying pointer is of type A or B, and call non-static function of appropriate class.

Answer (score 2):

**"a"** is a member of an object of type **"A"**.

This means you need to have an instance of **A** to access **a**.

So unless you make it also static, you'll need to make an object of type **A** (or **B**) and pass it as a parameter to the functions.

Besides, you can access an object's method with pthreads:

[Calling object functions in C++ with pthreads](http://timmurphy.org/2009/07/13/calling-object-functions-in-c-with-pthread/)

Comment: What you are saying is correct but this is not what I was looking for. I was looking for a solution when a class is inherited. Anyways, thanks for your help :-)